# https to http tomcat using nginx

Tags: tomcat, nginx

Hi I am using the following configuration in nginx and seams like 8443 port is open (I can use telnet $IP 8443, says port is open). No error in nginx logs also but still i am not able to open tomcat page which runs in same server in port 8080

```
server {
    listen      8443;
    server_name 214.244.195.55;
    root        /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/ROOT/;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cacert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privatekey.pem;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_SCHEME https;
    server_tokens off;

    index       index.html;
    include     mime.types;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://214.244.195.55:8080;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
       location = /40x.html {
    }

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

seprately if I access the http://214.244.195.55:8080 it works fine and loads me the tomcat page.

I dont see any logs in tomcat also when I try https://214.244.195.55:8443. Please let me know how to debug further.

Comment: Port 8443 is running SSL. Did you mean `https://214.244.195.55:8443/` in your question?

Comment: yes i have edited the question, it works via http when I drectly use tomcat url , but when i use https with nginx proxy url it doesn't work. I am not seeing any issue in logs also